# could the .not() method of jQuery have an integer for a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below and the part where it says `image.not(activeSlide).fadeOut(fade);` works but I don't see in the  [documents for jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/not/) that I could use a number as a parameter. `activeSlide` is an integer I think.

so can I use an integer for the .not() method? If so can you point out where I could find this particular info in the docs?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var image = $('#slider img');
    var numSlides = image.length;
    console.log(numSlides)
    var activeSlide = 0;
    var speed = 2000;
    var fade = 1000;
    var timer = setInterval(rotate, speed);

    image.eq(activeSlide).show();

    function rotate(){
        activeSlide++;

        if(activeSlide == numSlides){
            activeSlide = 0;
        }
        console.log(activeSlide);

        image.not(activeSlide).fadeOut(fade);
        image.eq(activeSlide).fadeIn(fade);
    }
});
```

Comment: It doesn't appear in the docs, it does in the source code : `return jQuery.grep(elements, function (elem) { return (jQuery.inArray(elem, qualifier) >= 0) !== not; });` in `.not`, http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=_winnow

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: However, `2` is definitely not an array, so I'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.not() is not fading out the one indexed image; it's fading out **all** images

For example:

```
$( "body" ).find( "div" ).not( 2 ).addClass( "blue" );
```

will cause all 'div's to get class "blue", including the one at index 2

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/gunderjt/zmxnF/

The reason its working in your case, is because you are fading out **all** the images and then fading in the one indexed image, which technically is what you want.

Comment: very helpful. so it looks like putting in the integer is useless for my desired effect. but what about @Benjamin Gruenbaum's comment (above) about it not appearing in the docs but it appears in the jQuery code. can i derive to the conclusion that the code allows you to put in an integer but there is no effect? Thanks

Comment: That would be my guess :).  Not sure if I would consider it a bug or a feature.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `not` and `eq` to achieve your desired result:

```
$("div").not(":eq("+activeSlide+")").css("background", "red");
```

see working example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/jf7qx/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is answer to your question not() function doesn't accept index so as per your example code, if you will remove the activeSlide e.g. not(activeSlide) to not()
then also it will work because it's considering activeSlide as element which is not available there so it hides everything and then show the next image using eq() using index of element.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but a solution to your problem:

Since only one slide seems to be shown at a time, the easier way is to just fade out the currently active slide and then fade in the new active slide:

```
function rotate(){
    image.eq(activeSlide).fadeOut(fade);
    activeSlide++;

    if(activeSlide == numSlides){
        activeSlide = 0;
    }
    console.log(activeSlide);

    image.eq(activeSlide).fadeIn(fade);
}
```